# I keep receiving an attribute error in Pygame when attempting to create a window

Tags: python, pygame

I have only today started using pygame, and am just getting familiar with how to use it. I want to start out by simply creating a blank window. I have attempted using the code below:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 300))
done = False

while not done:
    for event in pygame.display.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT():
            done = True
    pygame.display.flip()
```

However, the window appears for only a second before disappearing, followed by the error message:

> line 8, in 
>       for event in pygame.display.event.get():
>   AttributeError: module 'pygame.display' has no attribute 'event'

Can anyone help?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event queue is accessed via the function `pygame.event.get()`.  You are trying to use the pygame `display`.  Also `QUIT` is not a function.

Please try:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 300))
done = False

while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():   # <-- HERE
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:  # <-- AND HERE
            done = True
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation shows event as an attribute of the pygame module.  I think you should change the line to pygame.event.get().

This makes sense given the error.